# Change ending name of file without changing the extension

Tags: bash

I have the name of a file in $fich1 and i want to add "(copy)" at the end with the same extension(but maybe it does not have an extension).
For example, file1.txt to file1(copy).txt or im1 to im1(copy) .The only thing i can think of is something like this:

```
${fich1/./(copy).}
```

But this way if a file does not have an extension it wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Parameter Expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) can be used to extract name and extension (if present) and then stitch together to get new string as required

```
$ f='file1.txt'
$ name="${f%.*}"
$ ext="${f#${f%.*}}"
$ newname="${name}(copy)${ext}"
$ echo "$newname"
file1(copy).txt

$ f='file1'
$ name="${f%.*}"
$ ext="${f#${f%.*}}"
$ newname="${name}(copy)${ext}"
$ echo "$newname"
file1(copy)
```

If using with `mv` command:

```
$ f='file1.txt'
$ mv -v "$f" "${f%.*}(copy)${f#${f%.*}}"
'file1.txt' -> 'file1(copy).txt'

$ f='file2'
$ mv -v "$f" "${f%.*}(copy)${f#${f%.*}}"
'file2' -> 'file2(copy)'
```

Comment: yup, it will be empty